# Where can I get Wordpress Version in Dashboard?

Tags: wordpress-version

On the botton of the dashboard WP proposes to upgrade to next version but it doesn't even show current version: does it show it somewhere else ?

Comment: when you're upgraded to the latest version it shows the current version.

Answer (score 3):

go to your wp-admin dash board there in the Right Now box you will be able to see the currently installed version of your wordpress installation.

as shown in this picture below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj300.png]

Answer (score 3):

In a newer version of WordPress (3.8.3) the version number wasn't anywhere in plain sight on the dashborad for some reason (someone might have changed something on the site that I had to fix), but the WordPress logo in the upper left corner leads to an about page which says WordPress 3.8.3 (or the one you have) in huge letters.

This question might be 2 years old, but it's quite high on google, so I thought that if I drop this answer here, someone else might find it useful. After all, I got here after searching for an answer for this very question.

Answer (score 2):

You can visit `http://yourdomain.com/readme.html` file. This file is default in wordpress setup.

Comment: Hi Shail, this is more a guess than a real answer. It may be removed or not up to date as the file isn't needed for WordPress itself.

Comment: @kraftner I disagree, this file is part of core and being updated with it, as well as rarely removed in practice. It might not be absolutely reliable, but it's easy and practical method for quick look.

Comment: Some people remove this file for security reason. But its always updated.

Answer (score 1):

For WP version 4, you can check it under At A Glance box. If At A Glance is not visible, tick the option under Screen Options pull down menu. [image: WP Version Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

click on Dashboard then mark "At a Glance" in screen options. There you will get wordpress version you are using.